# Installation of R-package "BH" not possible

Tags: c++, r, boost, installation

I cannot install the [R-package BH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html) which I need only to install dplyr afterwards.

The download works but something is wrong with the processing afterwards, as there is no reaction or progress whatsoever. Installation of lubridate (and deinstallation of lubridate) in contrast worked smoothly without any problems.

My output is:

```
> install.packages("BH")
Installing package into ‘.../R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
versuche URL 'http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/bin/windows/contrib
/3.2/BH_1.58.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 13846684 bytes (13.2 MB)
downloaded 13.2 MB
```

and then nothing happens.

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior? Are there any prerequisites for the installation of BH?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: I just picked the _lubridate_ package to check whether there is generally something wrong with installing packages on my computer or it is just _BH_.

Comment: Yes, it can take quite a long time (several minutes) to install it on Windows. I have just installed the version `BH_1.72.0-3.zip`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

BH, as a sizeable subset of *B*oost *H*eaders is big, as in *really* big:

```
edd@max:~$ du -csm /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/
111     /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/
111     total
edd@max:~$
```

That is 111 megabytes.

You may simply have run our of patience if your Windows (network share ?) was slow in writing the files.

BH is also widely used by other CRAN packages, and there has not been a package on any of the platforms used by CRAN.

So I suggest you maybe place your R package library onto a local hard drive...

If you have an actual bug report, please consider filing an issue ticket against our BH package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, an overnight installation _almost_ worked. (unable to move temporary location from network share) I will try to move the package library to my local hard drive, didn't think about that earlier. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem -- there were two parts to my fix.

1/ Download the windows binary from CRAN and save to the hard disk.  You then select the menu item: Packages >> Install package(s) from local files…

2/ Edit the utils:::unpackPkgZip function to increase the sleep time – so that my virus checker has time to scan it.   To implement this, do the following:

`trace(utils:::unpackPkgZip, edit=TRUE)`

Look for the line `Sys.sleep(0.5)`, toward the bottom of the body of the function; it's a big package so I went for `Sys.sleep(10)`.

If you are still seeing the error: `Warning: unable to move temporary installation`, try a longer sleep period.

**Note** that you won't see the edit if you check `utils:::unpackPkgZip`; that is the unedited version, and it can be restored via `untrace(utils:::unpackPkgZip)`.

So see the edited version, use `body(utils:::unpackPkgZip)`.