# Trying to install dplyr in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install "dplyr" and it starts then stops and does not move after this point.

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘\\nwlondon.local/userdata/NWL_MyDocs/vijhar/My Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘BH’, ‘plogr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/BH_1.65.0-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17006683 bytes (16.2 MB)
downloaded 16.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/plogr_0.1-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17919 bytes (17 KB)
downloaded 17 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/dplyr_0.7.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2885543 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB
```

Comment: How long did you let it run? Absolutely nothing happened after that?

Comment: I let it run overnight, so about 16 hours. When I got back it was just stuck there, I tried it again the next day and the same thing happened.

Comment: Did you try to install all dependencies first (`BH`, `progr`)? With that you can isolate the problem further.

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone is having this issue, best way is to follow this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/README.html). I installed `tidyverse` (took about 15-20 mins)and then installed `dplyr` (Took about 8-10 mins).

Answer (score 0):

The `BH` package is very large (see the answer to [my similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272280/installation-of-r-package-bh-not-possible)). Can you make sure you do not install packages to a network drive and give the installation a night to run? That was what helped in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tonight!

Comment: did it work? If yes, maybe you can accept my answer. If not, you could share more details.

Comment: No it didn't, it has done the same thing where it keeps running and nothing really happens.